# pythonic way to sort a SortedDict

Tags: python, django, dictionary

SortedDict is a python dict with an additional attribute which uses as sorting,

```
sorted_dict = {
               'personnel info': {'name': 'p_info', 'priority': 1},
               'educational info': {'name': 'edu_info', 'priority': 3}
               'additional info': {'name': 'adi_info', 'priority': 2}
}
sorted_dict.keyOrder = ['personnel info', 'educational info', 'additional info']
```

now we can use this sorted dict in specific ordering wherever we use.

now i have to sort this dict according to priority i.e. key order should be on priority basis

```
>>>print sorted_dict.keyOrder
>>> ['personnel info', 'additional info', 'educational info']
```

any pythonic way (like sorted) to avoid forloop/function here.

note: i already have sortedDict with initial keyOrder.

Comment: Are you talking about a [Django SortedDict](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict)? The syntax you've shown doesn't look like valid syntax, and I don't see a `keyOrder` attribute in the docs.

Comment: You may be able to use `sorted_dict.keyOrder.sort(key=lambda k: sorted_dict[k]['priority'])`, depending on what the SortedDict API allows you to do with the `keyOrder` attribute.

Comment: @user2357112- yes i am talking about django SortedDict. of course we don't create sorted dict in such way, but it does have same keyOrder to maintain it's order, u can modify that attribute. i don't know whether thiese things are mentined in doc or not.

Comment: thank user2357112 but that is givin global variable sorted_dict undefined for lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the priority and keys and then sort based on priority i.e.

```
sorted_dict.keyOrder = [key[1] for key in sorted((v['priority'],k) for k,v in sorted_dict.items())]
```